# WCF : No password in SqlConnectionStringBuilder - why does it work?

Tags: c#, wcf, passwords, stringbuilder

I have my connexion String builder like this :

```
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "NAMEofSERVER",
                InitialCatalog = "NAMEofDATABASE",
                Encrypt = true,
                TrustServerCertificate = true,
                ConnectTimeout = 60,
                AsynchronousProcessing = true,
                MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
                IntegratedSecurity = true
            };
```

and I don't have a propriety "password" so how it's possible that my wcf service is good connected with my SQLServer dataBase? (I can to do INSERTs and UPDATES).

It's because it's in the same computer (my service WCF and my dataBase) or it's only in local and when I will to share my wcf the connexion will be refused?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnectionStringBuilder_IntegratedSecurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it considered your windows authentication to login to your SQLServer hence you don't need a userid and password in this case. But if your windows authentication is prohibited in the server then it will not allow to login even with your windows authentication.

Comment: Ok, thanks you a lot. And now, I need to share my service on another remote server. In this case I need to add  "Password ="  and "login=" yes?

Comment: Yes, and remove `IntegratedSecurity = true`

Comment: Yes if that server is on other machine. But if the server is also in windows you can request your DBA to add that account in SQLserver for secured login i.e. windows authentication. But still you can use userid and password for a successful login.